# After extracting data from html using a for loop, how do I insert one by one into a database?

Tags: java, html, list

I have extracted multiple data from an HTML using Jsoup and now I am trying to insert one by one into a derby db using JDBC on netbeans.

Here is my code:

```
public String nameOf() {
    String nameStr = null;
    String nameResults = "";

    for(int j=100;j<=110;j++) {
        refNum = j;

        //System.out.println("Reference Number: " + refNum);

        try {                
            //crawl and parse HTML from definition and causes page
            Document docDandC = Jsoup.connect("http://www.abcd.edu/encylopedia/article/000" + refNum + ".htm").get();

            // scrape name data
            Elements name = docDandC.select("title");

            nameStr = name.get(0).text();
            //System.out.println(nameStr);

            nameResults += nameStr + " ";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("Reference number " + refNum + " does not exist.");
        }            
    }
    return nameResults;
```

So this method takes the names of diseases from 10 different HTMLs. What I am trying to do is to insert one name at a time to a derby db that I have created using JDBC. I have everything set up and all I have left to do is to insert each name in the corresponding name field of a table named DISEASE (which has fields: id, name, etc).

```
nameResults += nameStr + " ";
```

This part worries me as well since some diseases can have multiple words. Maybe I should use a list of some sort?

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good idea, use a List.

Comment: Your question, title and tags are not in sync.  Do you really have question related o jdbc and derby here?  Your question was on data structure and is well answered.

Comment: @Jayan, well... My fault. I sorta mentioned that I have to insert each name in the "name" field of a table named "DISEASE" but I guess it didn't come off as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
public List<String> nameOf() {
    ...
    List<String> nameResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    nameResults.add(nameStr);
    ...
    return nameResults;
```